# Proper punctuation in dynamic <head> title, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been unsuccessful in figuring out how to display the punctuation properly in my `<head>` title.

I'm using this:

```
<%= provide(:title, "#{@artist.artist_name}") %>
```

which works fine unless someone's `artist_name` has a punctuation mark in it.

Example: when the title is `Test Me I'm Scared`, it will appear in the view as `Test Me I&20$m Scared`

Anyway to fix this?

Comment: i was thinking the same, Arup, but wouldn't this open them up to XSS?

Comment: @sircapsalot you are right.

Comment: @sircapsalot what is XSS?

Comment: @DBruns *It is recommended that you use [`sanitize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) instead of this method. It should never be called on user input.*

Comment: Cross-site scripting (XSS) is a type of computer security vulnerability typically found in web applications. XSS enables attackers to inject client-side script into web pages viewed by other users

Comment: @ArupRakshit You are correct. Good catch. You might want to delete your comment to prevent someone from making a mistake and using it.

Comment: Does anyone know of an SO question explaining when to use `html_safe` over `sanitize`? Also, @ArupRakshit your link to sanitize is actually to html_safe, where it says to use sanitize instead (but not explain its use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe sanitize should do the trick. Also the quotes are unnecessary.

`<%= provide(:title, sanitize(@artist.artist_name)) %>`

In addition to making the special characters display properly, this will scrub potential user input in artist_name to prevent a cross-site scripting vulnerability. It is very important to clean any user-generated data you spit back out to them.